# changing the background of a card (Android cardView)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am having a tough time changing the background color of a card in Android (cardView).

I did this in the XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#2600e622">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

But it did not work. I keeps defaulting to the white back ground color.

I am not sure where to go from here.
Any ideas?

Also - I want to position the card in the center of the screen and the card ends up being in the center but at the TOP of the screen. 
Can I get some insight on how to position the card in the center of the screen as well?

Thanks.

Comment: can you update with more xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#00490b">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        // add more views here

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to set programmatically:

```
card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Or in XML you can use this code:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have in your colors.xml this color for example:

`<color name="ambar400">#FFCA28</color>`

in your class use:

`card_name.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ambar400));`

Answer (score 0):

Set the color to your relative layout background if he is the root layout of your cardview:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:colorBackground="#2600e622">
```